# How to add jar file into the class-path while running another jar file during run time

Tags: java, scala, command-line, classnotfoundexception, executable-jar

I have a jar file(mts.jar) to run and it requires another jar(hook.jar) to be added at the runtime.

mts.jar is dependent on some of the classes present in hook.jar. 
And our requirement is to pass this hook.jar in classpath at runtime while running mts.jar.

I have tried the combinations below:

```
java -cp "bin:hook.jar" mts.jar ccp.mts.server.websocket.Server

java -cp "hook.jar" mts.jar ccp.mts.server.websocket.Server
```

I have also tried to set the classpath like below:

```
set CLASSPATH="C:\Users\Desktop\mts 4.3\hook.jar"
```

then tried running as usual like below :

```
java -cp mts.jar ccp.mts.server.websocket.Server
```

But I am getting **class not found exception**.

Where I might be wrong ?

Comment: would you display the whole exception track information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure both files are inside the same directory, then call it like this

`java -cp mts.jar;hook.jar ccp.mts.server.websocket.Server`

You can also specify whole path, e.g.:

`java -cp c:\mts.jar;c:\hook.jar ccp.mts.server.websocket.Server`

To run your application, make sure that class: *ccp.mts.server.websocket.Server* is located inside one of the JAR files and has *main* method.